# Copy Dialog Box Response to a Cell

Tags: google-apps-script, copy, prompt

So I am kind of new to Google Scripts, and am not sure what exactly I am doing wrong. I am trying to copy the results from a dialog box to a cell in google sheets. However, the current method I am trying is not working, and I get a response saying "Cannot Find Function to CopyTo in Object (Response)"

```
function Cancel() {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();

  var result = ui.prompt(
      'What day did you cancel?',
      'Please enter the date as mm/dd/yyy',
      ui.ButtonSet.OK_CANCEL);

  // Process the user's response.
  var button = result.getSelectedButton();
  var text = result.getResponseText();
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet(),
    row = sheet.getLastRow();

  if (button == ui.Button.OK) {
    // User clicked "OK".
    sheet.insertRowAfter(row);
      text.copyTo(sheet.getRange(row + 1, 1));
    ui.alert('The Date has Been Recorded');
  } else if (button == ui.Button.CANCEL) {
    // User clicked "Cancel".
    ui.alert('I did not get your name.');
  } else if (button == ui.Button.CLOSE) {
    // User clicked X in the title bar.
    ui.alert('You closed the dialog.');
  }
}
```

Could anyone take a look at my code and make suggestions on how I can go about copying the response to a cell. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

instead of: `text.copyTo(sheet.getRange(row + 1, 1));`

try: `sheet.getRange(row + 1, 1).setValue(text);`